# Google Maps API v3.22 reverting to old controls

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google yesterday released v3.22 of their maps api which moves a bunch of the standard controls.

According to the Google Blog at http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/new-controls-style-for-google-maps.html#gpluscomments you can temporarily revert to the old controls, but I can;t get this to work at all.

The blog post says to simply add `google.maps.controlsStyle = 'azteca'` before you initialize the map, but I'm still getting the old controls displayed and they clash with some of my custom controls.

I've tried adding the line right at the start of my `initialize()` routine (which sets up all of the map options and creates the `map` object; and also right before the `map = new google.maps.Map()` statement.

Has anyone got any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does your code look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: My code looks awful and sprawling! It's very much not worthy of being posted here so I'd have had to have written something from scratch (as you have, thanks). Thankfully it was, as I suspected, something very simple that didn't really need anything other than the code I included in the question that was copied direct from the Google blog post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:
google.maps.controlStyle = 'azteca';

Comment: That'll be a typo copied direct from the Google blog post :-( But that has sorted it.

Answer (score 3):

They have a typo in the post (and in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#top_of_page))

[Issue in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8618)

```
google.maps.controlsStyle = 'azteca';
```

should be:

```
google.maps.controlStyle = 'azteca';
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  google.maps.controlStyle = 'azteca'
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```