# Google Maps - make ZoomControl large

Tags: google-maps

I want to have large ZoomControl bar on my map.

Here is map options code:

```
var opcjeMapy = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: wspolrzedne, // var defined in other place
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false,
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    panControl: true,
    scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: true,zoomControl: true,
    overviewMapControl: false,
    streetViewControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
    },
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
    }                 
};
```

I have still small zoom control (+ and -).
Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Additionally (if someone to check it live) I can attach link to page with that map.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). [The posted code works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8rpdbLyh/).  How big is your `map` div?

Comment: Ok, thanks for advices and sorry for poor English.
In your fiddle I have still small zoom control (only +/- buttons).
I need bar like that: http://oi60.tinypic.com/2i96z41.jpg 
My map div is about 1300 x 700px.

Comment: How are you loading the API? That is the "old" control style, won't be supported much longer and not available in the current experimental version by default.

Comment: `<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>`

Comment: Note that API versions are released every 3 months or so and only three are ever available at a time, so the old controls will no longer be available in approximately 9 months...

Comment: Ok, so maybe I will use that new zoom control.. After all thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the current experimental version.  In that version, the old controls (zoom slider) are disabled by default. Use the following to get the old controls in that version:

```
google.maps.controlStyle = 'azteca';
```

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609693/google-maps-api-v3-22-reverting-to-old-controls)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8rpdbLyh/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
google.maps.controlStyle = 'azteca';
var geocoder;
var map;
var wspolrzedne = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);

function initialize() {
  var opcjeMapy = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: wspolrzedne, // var defined in other place
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false,
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    panControl: true,
    scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    overviewMapControl: false,
    streetViewControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
    },
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
    }
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), opcjeMapy);

  var locate = ['New York, NY', 'Newark, NJ', 'Baltimore, MD'];
  showLocation(locate);


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```